# Как получить расстояние элемента до края браузера?

Tags: javascript

Как получить расстояние элемента, по отношению краю окна браузера при скроле. 
Пробую через getBoundingClientRect()
но он показывает только один раз, а мне нужно что бы он отслеживал скрол, ставлю window.addEventListener("scroll",...
но он все равно не работает так как нужно, что бы получить новые координаты нужно обновится.

На JS

Comment: я правильно понимаю что вам нужно, к примеру, выводить в консоль координаты, при каждом скролле на странице?

Comment: совершено верно

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте сверху и снизу `<div id="elem">some text</div>` много текста чтобы наглядно был виден скролл, и при скролле в консоль будут выводиться координаты `#elem`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("elem").getBoundingClientRect());
})
```

```html
<div id="elem">some text</div>
```